# NodeJS mysql query returning wrong result

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql2

I'm getting [ { 'AVG(Price)': '31000.0000' } ] instead of '31000.0000

this is the function

```
async function getAveragePrice(year) {
const sql = await init();
const [rows] = await sql.query('SELECT AVG(Price) FROM Car where year= 
?', [year], (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
     return null;
  }
 });
 return rows;
}
```

I'm using nodejs mysql2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. the callback part is redundant
2. this is expected behavior, `.query(sql)` returns `Promise<array of rows>` and row is the object where each key is the corresponding field name

```js
async function getAveragePrice(year) {
  const db = await init();
  const [rows] = await db.query('SELECT AVG(Price) as avg FROM Car where year=?', [year])
  return rows[0].avg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
async function getAveragePrice(year) {
  const sql = await init()
  const row = await sql.query('SELECT AVG(Price) AS avg_price FROM Car where year=?', year, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      return null
    }
    return result.avg_price
  })
}
```